# can not mount EBS volume to centos EC2 instance

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have an ec2 instance running centos and I want to add an EBS want to it. I created and attached the volume to my instance. my volume is attached as /dev/sdf. But when I try to check if there is any filesystem by typing the command  **file -s /dev/xvdf here** as root, i get this message **:/div/xvdf: cannot open (No such file or directory)**
how should i do that? ?

Answer (score 0):

As you said your volume is `/dev/sdf`. Why you try to access is as `/dev/xvdf`? Also the error message you enter here mention `/div/xvdf` (wrong directory).

Also the proper command to check the partition on disk is:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdf
```

Comment: But on another ec2 instance that (file -s /dev/xvdf) command returns me /dev/xvdf: data

Comment: @leauradmin, you should care about current machine, not other. And what tell you the result of `file` command in this case?